# How to Send email of Linux Performance tunning and logwatch report in the form of csv report or doc file

Tags: linux, pdf, csv, report, doc

Can anyone help me for finding out how to send  email with different kind of performance or logwatch report in the form of CSV file,ppt/pdf or doc file.

Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to send attachments in an email from a linux command line (assuming you already have mail working), you can use uuencode.  This is a standard utility and is part of sharutils package in Centos and RHEL but may be other places in other distros.

With uuencode installed

`uuencode myfile.pdf myfile.pdf > attach`

This will create an encoded file called attach in the current directory from the file myfile.pdf (or .doc or any other binary or text file).  The syntax translates to: encode myfile.pdf and name the encoded attachment myfile.pdf and save it as a file called attach. You can then use

`mailx -s"My Subject" -r local_from_account@myhost.mydoman to_me@my_address.com < attach`

making the obvious substitutions.